# Android Studio detects import, but gives "Symbol cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, android, importerror

I have added a library to my project in Android Studio with various classes, one of which is PublicKey.java.

If I start to type PublicKey in a class in my project, java detects the file and shows me the full file name in the popup that I can click to auto-complete. Ie, I start typing PublicKey, and I can click org.abstractj.kalium.keys.PublicKey.

However, as soon as I do this, android studio then tells me it cannot resolve the symbol abstractj, despite the fact it must recognize it given that it just prompted me to use it. Any ideas on how to fix this?

(Note: this happens with any file in the library. I just use PublicKey as an example)

Comment: Your build.gradle in your project might not be configured correctly to consider that file a proper source file OR it might not be linking the right dependencies. I'll assume your SDK is properly set up because it's only the addition of the library that causes this error.

Comment: I have "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])" in my build.gradle dependencies so it should be loading the library, which is just a .jar in my libs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with the library itself. I had made a mistake in assembling the jar.